# LU decomposition of a CSR matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix

I store a sparse matrix A in Compressed Sparse Row format (CSR). I would like to compute the LU decomposition of A. Common algorithms are not very efficient since they must loop on all coefficients of the matrix. Is there an efficient algorithm that takes advantage of the CSR format to compute the LU decomposition?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you asking if that algorithm exists or if it's implemented in some library you're using? (the answers are yes and almost surely).

Comment: I was asking whether an algorithm exists, because the naive version of the LU decomposition is not adapted to CSR storage. So I wondered if I could find a way to keep my CSR format and find a nice LU factorization algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) library. The la4j supports CRS format as well as LU decomposition. So, you can try to use it. But, la4j (0.4.0) doesn't really handle concreet format details while perfroming decompositions. But this what I'm planing to do in next realeases. You can [subscribe](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j) to updates or try to implement such algorithm by yourself and send a pull-request to la4j.

How to use LU decompositor:

```
Matrix a = new CRSMatrix(new double[][]{ 
  {1.0, 2.0}, 
  {3.0, 4.0}
});

// lu[0] - L, lu[1] - U
Matrix[][] lu = a.decompose(Matrices.LU_DECOMPOSITOR);
```